# history in react router whit private route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to redirect my user on some page whit `history.push('/route')` but if i use it the url change 
but the component is not rendering.

The router:

```js
// vanilla
import React from 'react';
// router
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
// component
import Login from '../controller/Login';
import history from '../history';
import Content from './Content';
import Categories from './Categories';
import Author from './Author';
import NavbarView from '../view/Navbar.view';

function PrivateRoute({children, ...rest}: any) {
  const jwtExist = !!localStorage.getItem('jwt');
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={ ({location}) =>
        jwtExist ?
          (children) :
          (<Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: location}}}/>)
      }
    />
  )
}

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
        <PrivateRoute path='/admin'>
          <NavbarView/>
          <Route path={'/admin/contents'} component={Content} />
          <Route path={'/admin/categories'} component={Categories} />
          <Route path={'/admin/authors'} component={Author} />
        </PrivateRoute>
      </Router>
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

And the "redirect" :

```js
import history from '../history';

const checkJwt: () => any = () => {

  fetch('http://localhost:3001/auth/validate', {
    headers: {
      'Authorization' : `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('jwt')}`
    }
  })
    .then((res: any) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.status !== 200) {
        history.push('/login')
      }
    })
};

export default checkJwt;
```

If i try to put `history` in my router like this :

```js
<Router history={history}>
```

i get the following error :

```js
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<BrowserRouterProps>): BrowserRouter', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; history: History<any>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter> & Readonly<BrowserRouterProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
      Property 'history' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter> & Readonly<BrowserRouterProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: BrowserRouterProps, context?: any): BrowserRouter', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element[]; history: History<any>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter> & Readonly<BrowserRouterProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
      Property 'history' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter> & Readonly<BrowserRouterProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.  TS2769

    33 |   render() {
    34 |     return (
  > 35 |       <Router history={history}>
       |        ^
    36 |         <Route path='/login' component={Login}/>
    37 |         <PrivateRoute path='/admin'>
    38 |           <NavbarView/>
```

My history file look like this :

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use the Router from `"react-router-dom"`

Replace

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
```

with

```
import {
  Router,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
```

as BrowserRouter does not accept history prop.
This works for me.